# What kind of graph could I use to achieve this with ChartJS (or similar)?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to make a deciBel-frequency chart like this in javascript: 
[image]

[*X axis is frequency domain (red, blue and yellow are 4G bands), Y axis is power in dB*]

However, the classic bar chart that I find in every library cannot fix the bottom of the bars below 0. I'm trying to find another kind of chart that I could use to achieve this. Orange color is the noise floor power.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far in ChartJs?

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco I've tryed changing some parameters of the bar-type chart, but the bar bottom starts at 0, which is the main problem. here's a simple try: https://jsfiddle.net/now4Lcr1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to create "range" only by `one` value.

For example, the data for the **red** bar in your example is **not** only `20` -or- `-180` but `-180 to 20` = `nested array` ([Multidimensional Array](https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/multidimensional.php))

```
data = [[-180,20]];
```

### snippet:

```js
labels1 = ["a","b","c","d"];
data = [[20,-180],[40,-160],[20,-120]];

var data = {
  labels: labels1,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "hello",
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: ["yellow", "blue", "orange"],
      borderWidth: 5
    } 
  ]
}

var options = {
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{ 
      stacked: false,
    }],
    yAxes: [{ 
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: true
        },
        max: 100,
        min: -180,
      }
    }]
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: name
  },
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
  },
};


/*for(let i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
 let labels2 = [];
 let datos2 = [];
 labels2.push(i);
 datos2.push(-120);
}*/



var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options:options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<h2>
Hello World!
</h2>
<canvas  id='myChart'/>
```